# Send only filled inputs values to database via SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have dozens of inputs in an HTML table one can use to enter numerical values. When submit button is pressed all inputs values are added to their corresponding column in the SQL table via `post` method. Value of `<input name="A1>` will be sent to column A1 in SQL table, `<input name="A2>` to column A2, and so on.

I'm currently using something like this (but with dozens of parameters) to insert data in my table :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO all_stats_table (A1, A2, A3) VALUES ($A1, $A2, $A3)";
```

Problem with this approach is that every input needs to be filled or it will result in an SQL error. I initially used php to set all empty inputs value to 0 before sending everything to database, but I don't think this method is the most efficient way to go.

I would rather like to dynamically check which inputs are actually filled and only send their values to the table instead of converting every empty input value to 0 and having to send everything to the database.

I've already set all default values to 0 in SQL, but I don't know how to only send filled input values via SQL. I tried using a php foreach loop but I'm definitely having trouble finding the right SQL syntax.

Is what I'm trying to do possible ? If not, what would be the best practice to make this process more efficient ?

Thank you for your help

---

**EDIT :** attempt to adapt akash raigade's great solution to non-numbered SQL columns :

HTML :

```
<input name='name'>
<input name='address'>
<input name='age'>
```

PHP :

```
$Field_list = array ('name','address','age');

$field_string = ''; 
$input_string = ''; 

foreach ($_POST as $userInfo=>$userInfo_value) {
    if (isset($userInfo)) {
        if ($field_string == '') {
            $field_string = $field_string.$userInfo; //problem here ?
            $input_string = $userInfo_value; //problem here ?
        }
        else {
            $field_string = $field_string.','.$userInfo; //problem here ?
            $input_string = $input_string.','.$userInfo_value; //problem here ?
        }
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO protocole_test (".$field_string.") VALUES (".$input_string.")"; 
echo $sql ; //check query formed
```

Comment: Use prepared statements http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Upgraded version]**

Basic idea is that we keep NAME attribute of INPUT same as table column-name where it is gonna be stored.Then with help of input tag name and value which are filled we prepare SQL statement which have only required (FILLED) columns and values.

For given example consider following MYSQL table :

```
 sr.no.|name|age|gender
```

**CODE [Tested]:**

```
<input name="name" >
<input name="age" >
<input name="gender" >
<input type='submit'>

<?php 
$field_string ='';
$input_string='';
foreach  ($_POST as $userInfo=>$userInfo_value){
    if($userInfo_value !=''){
        echo $userInfo."->".$userInfo_value;
        if ($field_string == '') {
            $field_string = $field_string.$userInfo; 
            $input_string = $userInfo_value; 
        }
        else {
            $field_string = $field_string.','.$userInfo; 
            $input_string = $input_string.','.$userInfo_value; 
        }
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO protocole_test (".$field_string.") VALUES (".$input_string.")"; 
echo $sql ; //check query formed
?>
```

---

[original answer]Have a look at following code :

```
<input name='a1' id='input_for_name'>
<input name='a2' id='input_for_class'>
<input name='a3' id='input_for_seat.no'>
.
.
<input name='an' id='input_for_n'>
```

Now

```
    <?php

//you must be having field list to be inserted i.e
//INSERT INTO all_stats_table >>>(A1, A2, A3)<<< VALUES ($A1, $A2, $A3)
//A1,A2,A3 is field list here 

//so save them into an array.
$Field_list = array ('A1','A2','A3',.......'An');

//Now get which input_field is inputted by :
$i=0;
$field_string = '';
$input_string = '';
for($i<n){
if(isset($_POST['a'.$i])){

   if ($field_string == ''){
      $field_string = $field_string.$Field_list[$i];
      $input_string = $_POST['a'.$i];

}
   else {
   $field_string = $field_string.','.$Field_list[$i];
   $input_string = $input_string.','.$_POST['a'$i];
}}}
    $sql = "INSERT INTO (".$field_string.") VALUES (".$input_string.")";
//to check query formed 
echo $sql ;
    ?>
```

**Explanation :**

We check which input field is FILLED , if it is field we add its FIELD into FIELD LIST and ITS VALUE in INPUT LIST finally we GENERATE SQL STATEMENT.

Comment: Thank you ! Your solution is very elegant and teached me a lot ! But although it works perfectly with SQL numbered columns, it won't work when the columns need to have specific names (to store a different type of data). I tried to adapt your solution to this case using a for loop, which works fine when all inputs are filled but I can't get it to work when one or more field is empty. I edited my question to show you what I tried and where I think the problem is. Thank you again

Comment: @Nora i am feeling glad that it works and teached u alot ! i have seen your edit , will check and give a solution back

Comment: But Can you attach the echo $sql in last case ? i will be more helpful for me to get whats problem or if $sql is not echoing due to any error pls post errors

Comment: Your solution fixed the problem, everything works fine now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just check if they are not defined or empty, and if so, define them.

```
if ( (!isset($_POST['A1'])) || (empty($_POST['A1']) ){
      $A1 = '0';
} else {
      $A1 = $_POST['A1'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did something like this in a previous test : `$A1 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/',"", $_POST['A1']) ?: 0;` (delete all non-digits characters and set empty value to 0), but I had to copy-paste this statement for each and every variable, and I though there might be a more efficient way. I may be missing something obvious though, as I'm still a newbie with php/SQL.

Comment: @Nora  Either approach could be converted to a function.. Let me ponder that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this and it may need some debugging, but you could create a function, then call the function for each input. Something like...

```
function chkinput($input){

if ( (!isset($_POST[$input])) || (empty($_POST[$input]) ){
    $$input = '0';
} else {
    $$input = $_POST[$input];
}
return $$input;
}

// You could potentially loop through the post array
// but here I just call the function once per input
chkinput('A1');
chkinput('A2');
...
chkinput('A12');
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution definitely helped me to understand better the use of unknown variable names ! your code will still send all the inputs value instead of sending only the inputed ones though. I'll see if it's possible to adapt it by looping through the post array.

Comment: fyi the $$variable  is technically called a "variable variable" and they can be pretty handy sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

You loop through the `$_POST` array and check if it has a value. If it does concatenate it to an variable. Like this:

```
$fields = "";
$values = "";

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
  if($value != ''){
    if($value != end($_POST)){
      $fields .= $key . ", ";
      $values .= "'" . $value . "', ";
    }else{
      $fields .= $key;
      $values .= "'" . $value . "'" ;
    }
  }  
}

$sql = INSERT INTO protocole_test ($fields) VALUES ($values) ;
```

Your SQL would look like :

```
INSERT INTO protocole_test (A1, A2, A3) VALUES ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')
```